# execution time of a method is increasing why is it so?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, visual-studio-2013

I have a method where I do the following

1. I add values to the class object
2. check for the difference in the database using Entity FrameWork

However the Execution time of the method is increasing continuously, despite the parameters not varying (only the values change).

Below are the contents of my method:

```
sw.Start();

details.EffectiveDate = cb.Attribute("dte_effective").Value.GetDate();
details.EndDate = cb.Attribute("dte_end").Value.GetDate();
details.MaxRefills = cb.Attribute("qty_refill").Value.ToIntOrNull();
details.Sex = cb.Attribute("cde_sex").Value == "B" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb.Attribute("cde_sex").Value) ? (string)null : cb.Attribute("cde_sex").Value.Substring(0, 1);
details.RxLimit = cb.Attribute("cde_rx_limit").Value.ToBoolOrNull();
details.WEAC = fullDoc.Descendants("weacPrice").Select(d => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(d.Attribute("amt_npt_price").Value)).FirstOrDefault();
details.EAC = fullDoc.Descendants("eacPrice").Select(d => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(d.Attribute("amt_npt_price").Value)).FirstOrDefault();
details.FederalMAC = fullDoc.Descendants("fulPrice").Select(d => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(d.Attribute("amt_mac").Value)).FirstOrDefault();
details.StateMAC = fullDoc.Descendants("macPrice").Select(d => (decimal?)decimal.Parse(d.Attribute("amt_mac").Value)).FirstOrDefault();
//there are few more

var currRestrictions = db.NDCDiagRestrictions.Where(n => n.NDC == NDC).ToList();

var newRestrictions = fullDoc.Descendants("diagRestriction")
                             .Select(d => new NDCDiagRestriction()
                             {
                                 NDC = NDC,
                                 DiagFrom = long.Parse(d.Attribute("cde_diag_from").Value),
                                 DiagTo = long.Parse(d.Attribute("cde_diag_to").Value),
                                 EffectiveDate = d.Attribute("dte_effective").Value.GetDate(),
                                 EndDate = d.Attribute("dte_end").Value.GetDate()
                             })
                             .ToList();

var joined = from n in newRestrictions
             from c in currRestrictions
             where n.DiagTo == c.DiagTo
                && n.EffectiveDate == c.EffectiveDate
                && n.EndDate == c.EndDate
                && n.DiagFrom == c.DiagFrom
                && n.NDC == c.NDC
             select n.NDC;

if (newRestrictions.Count != currRestrictions.Count
    || newRestrictions.Count != joined.Count())
{
    foreach (var rm in currRestrictions)
        db.NDCDiagRestrictions.Remove(rm);

    foreach (var ad in newRestrictions)
        db.NDCDiagRestrictions.Add(ad);
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

sw.Restart();
```

And the Time Elapsed is as follows:

95, 95, 104, 109, 192, 201, 218, 418, 447, 452, 459, 495, 504, 528, 1060, 1065, 1072, 1146, 1154, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually resetting the stopwatch? Showing *all* of the relevant code is important, you haven't included your declaration for `sw`.

Comment: If only all performance related issues were this simple to solve ;)

Comment: I have the stopwatch.restart() i forgot to include.....sorry my apologies.. It is the output after that...

Comment: Why are you restarting the stopwatch at the end of the method?  By doing so, you are timing whatever happens from the time the method ends to the next time the starts.

Answer (score 6):

You are starting the `Stopwatch` again from the point it was stopped. You need [`Stopwatch.Restart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart(v=vs.110).aspx) method, or you can call `Stopwatch.Reset` method before starting.

```
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
```

or

```
sw.Restart();
```